# Can i use 47uf instead of 10uf in LM317 Adjustable voltage regulated circuit?

Tags: voltage, capacitor, voltage-regulator, capacitance, lm317

[image][image][image]

Please refer the images above for the circuit, my question is can i use 2x47uf cap instead of 2x10uf cap in the circuit, since i dont have any 10uf cap in my hand, Thanks.

Comment: Try it and see. You should be fine. Assuming you are not making a million of em and it's a one off project that isn't safety critical then experiment. Only change is I'd add a reverse diode from out to in of the 317 so the higher capacitance on the output doesn't reverse drive it. It's a good idea in general anyway.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about connecting diode from Out to In of 317 regulator. 1N4002 is good right??!

Comment: As John says, 2 x 47 uF almost certainly OK. | 1N4002 is fine for reverse diode. It stops the output capacitordischarging into the LM317 if the input is shorted or in input voltage is removed suddenly.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon The diode is not necessary if you won't load or short the input voltage. The LED current isn't enough to worry about. It does no harm of course, unless you put it in backwards (!) and then it's mostly the load that gets it.

Comment: @SpehroPefhany This is in the "I know you know" category - It's more for Pradeep & others. | I completely agree (of course) that as posed, just as seat belts and helmets are not needed if you never use them :-), there is almost certainly not going to be a problem. But if Pradeep build this circuit AND also loads the transformer heavily with some other load, then "one day" when he turns it off  or a short or heavier load is  used on the other circuit, and the LM317 quietly dies, he would wonder why. In reality I suspect that the <= 88 mJ of energy in the 47 uF probably wouldn't bother the LM317

Answer (score 2):

You can double-check the design of that power supply using the information in the [Texas Instruments LM317 datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm317.pdf).

At page 10 you find this:

[image]

which is followed by a detailed design procedure.

The important thing to note is that Co is not required for stability, so it simply improves transient response, i.e. it makes the output react faster when the load changes abruptly (the IC is comparatively slow in this respect, if the load change is very quick and you need the output not to change briefly during the transient). So you have substantial freedom in choosing its value. 47uF is OK (it can be also of aluminium electrolytic type, if you don't need particular high frequency rejection), especially if you plan to connect heavy loads at the the output.

Ci is not critical either, but it *might* be required for stability, if the distance from the 470uF filter cap is substantial (several centimeters, maybe), so it is better to be some ceramic or polymer type (PP or similar), definitely NOT aluminium electrolytic (I often went for some 100-220nF PP type in hobbysts, one-off designs). The 10uF value in your schematic is weird, unless it is of a ceramic type, since it is too high to be a reasonable polymer type, and an aluminium electrolytic doesn't do any good there.

The diodes D1 and D2 are always a good safety measure, since it is a circuit that is designed to be connected to unknown loads, so who knows how much input capacitance the load has and if you turn off you power supply with a load attached, its internal capacitance could discharge into your LM317 and damage it.

As a side note, the value of R1=240Ω might be "wrong" (even in the datasheet!). The datasheet implicitly assumes a "substantial" load is applied to the output. In fact the LM317 needs a minimum of 10mA of load current to work properly, as stated in this table from the datasheet:

[image]

R1=240Ω, having 1.25V across it, will draw only about 5mA, which is not enough in a worst case scenario with either no or a light load connected (which is not unusual for a lab power supply). It will work for the typical 3.5mA required, but you don't want to rely on that in corner cases. An R1=120Ω makes the design more robust and guarantees that the minimum current needed for regulation is drawn even with no load.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, bottom line is that your suggested substitute 47uF (**assuming adequate voltage rating which you didn't mention!!**) will be fine- better than the original. If the voltage rating is not high enough (higher is fine) the caps may fail with a bang.

See the LM317 [datasheet](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm117.pdf):

[image]

They recommend 25uF or greater aluminum electrolytic to ensure no problems. The input capacitor is redundant if you keep the distance to the 470uF under 6" (150mm).

A note on the datasheet. Solid tantalum caps are rare these days (and expensive). The 317 was designed by Bob Dobkin (co-founder of LTC) in the mid-1970s when he was at National Semi (bought recently by TI) and capacitor technology has changed in the last 40 years. Aluminum electrolytics are available in low impedance versions now, and high capacitance ceramic caps have become more available (though they tend to shrink greatly in capacitance when biased- for most high capacitance types- so a 10uF ceramic cap might be 3 or 4uF when you put full voltage across it). Low impedance electrolytics or solid polymer types could be used in this circuit too, and they might be a bit better, but they are not necessary.

Comment: Thanks for all your replies. Instead of powering the circuit with a 12v 1amp transformer, can i use a 30v .4amp(12watt) adapter from my printer. ? Thanks

Comment: Sure. Assuming that's 30VDC it will work well.  Consider fusing the secondary at 400mA and use a big heatsink (400mA * 30V = 12W, which the regulator will have to dissipate if you try to use a low voltage 400mA load. Commercial linear bench supplies sometimes have a relay to switch between different voltage sources. You could do the same thing and switch manually between a 30V and (say) a 12V or 19V source for lower output voltages.